# How to Run Activity only once?

Tags: java, android

please any help ? I just want to run an Android studio Application and the first Activity is an EditText and button when the user enter his/her age the application will run as his/her age ...
and it's just run once  ++ here is my code please help me:):):)
 And thanx in Advance.
Sorry about my English,,,

```
 package com.example.administrator.muslimsapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("appInfo", 0);
    boolean firstTime = settings.getBoolean("first_time", true);
    if (firstTime) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first_time", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public void clickme(View view) {
    EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    String ed=edt.getText().toString();
    if(ed==""){
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    if(Integer.parseInt(ed)<=13){
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if(Integer.parseInt(ed)>13){
        Intent i2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
        startActivity(i2);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: How is `clickme` being called? Seems like you need to register a button `OnClickListener` within your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Additionally, `ed==""` will not work. This is a comparison for object equality, not a test for strings being the same. Use `ed.trim().length()==0`.

Comment: you can use ed.equals("") for string comparison.

Comment: @codebod i have called it from xml file ...

Comment: i have no issue with ed=="" but thanks :)

Comment: `ed==""` will NEVER be true. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/13373270.

Answer (score 0):

Your programme always requires the user to click your button. Add an `else` branch at the end of `onCreate`.

```
if(firstTime) {
   ...
} else {
     startActivity(...);
     finish();
}
```